# Probability of 2-digit appearing in random 3 digit number?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have {1, 2} what is the probability of them both appearing in three digit number?

[1x2, 2x1, 12x, 21x, x12, x21]

I tried the following but is not getting the correct answer

1 - P(Both not appear) - P(Only 1 appear) = 1 - 0.8 * 0.8 * 0.8 - 0.2 * 0.8 * 0.8 *3 = 0.104.

The answer should be 0.054. What is wrong with my work?

**EDIT**

I manage to work it out

1- P(Three Others)-P(Three 1s)-P(Three 2s)-P(Two 1s,no 2)-P(Two 2s,no 1)-P(One 1,no 2)-P(One 2,no 1)

=1-0.8^3-2*0.1^3-2*3*0.1^2*0.8-2*3*0.1*0.8^2=0.054

Comment: what about 112 or 121 etc?

Comment: That is included too

Answer (score 1):

What you calculated is the probability of getting a 3-digit number where at least two of the numbers are either a $1$ or a $2$. But note that that would include such numbers as $111$ and $226$, which is not what you want. So, you need to make sure you get at least one $1$ *and* at least one $2$

To repair this, you can subtract the ones as indicated: you have exactly one $111$ and exactly one $222$.  Now you need to subtract the ones with two $1$'s and something that's neither a $1$ or a $2$ (so there are 8 digits times 3 locations = 24 such numbers) and finally the ones with $2$'s and something that's neither a $1$ or a $2$ (also 24).  Subtracting those $1+1+24+24=50$ patterns should get you from $104$ to $54$ as desired

Or, in terms of probability: the probability of getting $111$ is $0.1\cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.1=0.001$. Likewise, the probability of getting $222$ is $0.001$.  The probability of getting two $1$'s and something that's neither a $1$ or a $2$ is $0.1\cdot0.1\cdot 0.8\cdot3=0.024$, and likewise the probability of getting two $2$'s and something that's neither a $1$ or a $2$ is $0.024$

Comment: Can I use binomial probability for this? Also will it be easier to do (1 - something)?

Comment: I would stick to the (1-something method) ... you already got rid of ther patterns with no or just 1 $1$ or $2$.  But as my Answer indicated, you need to subtract a few more patterns: the $111$ and the $222$, and the ones with two $1$'s and something that's neither a $1$ or a $2$, and finally the ones with $2$'s and something that's neither a $1$ or a $2$

Comment: @Zanko And yes, you can still use binomials for all those patterns

Comment: Using binomial i can only get this 1-〖0.8〗^3-2*〖0.1〗^3-2*3*〖0.1〗^2*0.8 = 0.438 which is still not 0.054

Comment: 1- P(Three Others)-P(Three 1s)-P(Three 2s)-P(Two 1s,no 2)-P(Two 2s,no 1)

Comment: Oh I forgot one more case which is exactly 1 and no 2s! Got it now!

Comment: @Zanko Yay!  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a good start with the six patterns; now you just have to figure out how many ways there are to fill in the $x$.  To avoid problems of double-counting, I would first count only the cases where $x\neq1,2.$  Then I'd count separately the ways to get two $1$s and a $2$ or two $2$s and a $1$.

I get $.052$ though, not $.054$ are you sure that's supposed to be the answer?

Comment: Yes, out of all 3 digits number from 000 to 999 there are 54 that contains "1" and "2".

Comment: That explains it.  I didn't count $012$ and $021$ as three-digit numbers.  I'm surprised that your source counts them.